# Brownie Github Actions workflow

Tags: python, chainlink, brownie, evm

I am trying to deploy smart contracts on Ethereum Sepolia testnet using python brownie `eth-brownie`==1.19.3. My scripts work locally, but I want to deploy from Github Actions directly for a CICD pipeline for smart contracts.

Does anyone have a `workflow.yaml` for brownie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `workflow.yaml` below works for me.
To implement this add the following variables to your repo in
Settings > Secrets and variables > Actions:

RPC HTTP URL FOR BLOCKCHAIN CONNECTIVITY:

`RPC_URL=REDACTED`

EXLORER URL API KEY FOR CONTRACT VERIFICATION:

`ETHERSCAN_TOKEN=REDACTED`

HOT WALLET PRIVATE KEY DEPLOYING THE CONTRACT

`PRIVATE_KEY=REDACTED`

NODE ADDRESS WHICH SERVES THE ORACLE REQUESTS TO THE CONTRACT

`NODE_ADDRESS=REDACTED`

WALLET ADDRESS TO OWN THE CONTRACT AFTER DEPLOYMENT & FULFILLMENT

`OWNER_ADDRESS=REDACTED`

The `workflow.yaml` is default set to Ethereum Sepolia, if deploying to another network, be sure to configure L25 (brownie netowks add YOUR_NETWORK...) in .github/workflows/workflow.yaml

```
name: Brownie Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.9.13

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: pip install eth-brownie==1.19.3

    - name: Add Brownie network
      run: brownie networks add Ethereum sepolia chainid=11155111 host=${{ secrets.RPC_URL }} explorer=https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api

    - name: Compile contracts
      run: brownie compile

    - name: Deploy contracts
      env:
        PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
        ETHERSCAN_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ETHERSCAN_TOKEN }}
        OWNER_ADDRESS: ${{ secrets.OWNER_ADDRESS }}
        NODE_ADDRESS: ${{ secrets.NODE_ADDRESS }}
      run: brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network sepolia
```

[Reference](https://github.com/Block-Farms/Github-Actions-Brownie-Oracle/tree/main)